# "Authentication Required" with NSURLSession. User/Key correct

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C and am struggling to get the following code to work properly. Logging out `dataString` is telling me that the API is returning an "Authentication Required" message. When I put the resulting URL into a browser, however, the information I want is returned correctly. What am I missing? Is NSURLSession doing something to change the request?

```
- (void)fetchWX
{
    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@@flightxml.flightaware.com/json/FlightXML2/Metar?airport=%@", FLIGHTAWARE_USERNAME, FLIGHTAWARE_API_KEY, _airport];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", dataString);
}];

[dataTask resume];
}
```

There's another method in my app with a similar structure that's working properly, and FlightAware's synchronous example using NSURLConnection also works fine. Just can't seem to use NSURLSession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{ @"Accept":@"application/json"};
NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"jsonObject is %@",jsonObject);
}];
```

and add this delegate method, which will be called once to resolve the authentication challenge.

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler {

    NSString *user = @"YourUserName";
    NSString *password = @"YourKey";

    NSLog(@"didReceiveChallenge");

    // should prompt for a password in a real app but we will hard code this baby
    NSURLCredential *secretHandshake = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    // use block
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,secretHandshake);
}
```

I have tested it and it worked.